# Django request get parameters

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

In a Django request I have the following:

```
POST:<QueryDict: {u'section': [u'39'], u'MAINS': [u'137']}>
```

How do I get the values of `section` and `MAINS`?

```
if request.method == 'GET':
    qd = request.GET
elif request.method == 'POST':
    qd = request.POST

section_id = qd.__getitem__('section') or getlist....
```

Comment: Never invoke one of the magic methods directly. Always use the appropriate helper function.

Comment: k is there any way to decode sections

Comment: Read through django documentation on these objects: http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#querydict-objects . There are some differences compared to dict in python.

Answer (score 114, accepted):

You can use `[]` to extract values from a `QueryDict` object like you would any ordinary dictionary.

```
# HTTP POST variables
request.POST['section'] # => [39]
request.POST['MAINS'] # => [137]

# HTTP GET variables
request.GET['section'] # => [39]
request.GET['MAINS'] # => [137]

# HTTP POST and HTTP GET variables (Deprecated since Django 1.7)
request.REQUEST['section'] # => [39]
request.REQUEST['MAINS'] # => [137]
```

Comment: just a hint after all these years: request.REQUEST is meanwhile deprecated

Answer (score 225):

You may also use:

```
request.POST.get('section','') # => [39]
request.POST.get('MAINS','') # => [137] 
request.GET.get('section','') # => [39]
request.GET.get('MAINS','') # => [137]
```

Using this ensures that you don't get an error. If the POST/GET data with any key is not defined then instead of raising an exception the fallback value (second argument of .get() will be used).